# What is the correct way in python to annotate a path with type hints?

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing, pathlib

What is the proper way to annotate this simple utility function in python3 that reads from a file?
It should accept `pathlib.Path` objects as well as any other common way of passing a path.

```py
def read_json(path: <TYPE HINT>):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data
```

It seems to me as if this topic is in flux and I couldn't find a good place where this information was collected. I am interested in how to handle this in python 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I assume that typical path objects are either `Path`s or `str`s, as such you could use a [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union). In addition, the more inclusive `os.PathLike` is preferred over `pathlib.Path`.

**Python 3.10 or newer:**

```py
import os

def read_json(path: str | os.PathLike):
    ...
```

**Python 3.5 - 3.9:**

```py
import os
import typing

def read_json(path: typing.Union[str, os.PathLike]):
    ...
```

Comment: Is there anywhere the standard functions are shown with type annotations?  I couldn't find one, but "copy the annotation for `open` would be a good answer.

Comment: ```open``` uses ```file: _OpenFile``` as annotation, which is the union ```Union[AnyPath, int]```.

Comment: I use this `PathLike = TypeVar("PathLike", str, pathlib.Path, None)`.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel (@maf88), the `os` module has `os.PathLike` which is a superclass of `pathlib.Path` and can be directly used. I think the answer should be edited to `Union[str, os.PathLike]`

Comment: @YotamWConstantini Yep, but Pathlike did not exist in 2019

Comment: This no longer works with recent mpv releases: Missing type parameters for generic type "PathLike"

Comment: (I don't know how I managed to misspell mypy as mpv.  StackOverflow, in its infinite wisdom, no longer lets me edit my comment because more than 5 minutes have passed.)

Comment: Why does DBAPI use StrOrBytesPath rather than str | Pathlike